# How to convert string variable to an array in php?

Tags: php

I have one string variable as

```
$p_list="1,2,3,4";
```

i want to convert it to an array such as

```
$a[0]='1';
$a[1]='2';
$a[2]='3';
$a[3]='4';
```

how to do this in php?

Answer (score 3):

Use **[explode](http://www.php.net/explode)**.

```
$p_list = "1,2,3,4";
$array = explode(',', $p_list);
```

See **[Codepad](http://codepad.org/8OCPJi1L)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try explode `$a=explode(",","1,2,3,4");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In PHP, explode function will convert string to array, If string has certain pattern.

<?php
        $p_list = "1,2,3,4";

        $noArr = explode(",", $p_list);  

        var_dump($noArr);
?>

You will get array with values stores in it.
```

- Thanks